# Import Linked in profile by using LinkedIn email and password with my website page without redirecting LinkedIn website page?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

My requirement is as below,
I have web page own login page when i enter email and password and click on Connect to LinkedIN button then  request goes to linkedin and import LinkedIn profile (same as fetching google contact list) and display my web page without redirecting to linkedin authorization page or without embed Linkedin Import profile button in my application.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, what you want to do is against the LinkedIn API terms of service:

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-apis-terms-use

> In order to access member specific Content through the APIs, your users must sign-in with their LinkedIn credentials and grant your Application access to their Content.

Your users can't sign in through your own site and then be automatically logged into LinkedIn without first authorizing your access.